# Are we able to run Orange from Python program

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-mining, orange

Currently, I am using the Orange data mining software tool to experiment my data.
Are we able to run Orange from Python script instead of using the software (can we write some python code to execute the program?).
I have a Python script to generate data files.I want to write a Python script to use different functionalities from Orange.
Is that possible. Do we have a tutorial for that?
Thanks

Comment: Did you know that you can call any program from within Python? If that program supports headless, non-interactive interaction then you can do a whole lot in this way. It might require you to write a few configuration files and input files, which is common practice. I suggest you look into the documentation of Orange to find out what interactions can be done with a simple call to the Orange executable or search for "scripting interface" or "API" on the Orange documentation.

Comment: See http://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/data-mining-library.

Comment: Oliver, Orange is already a Python library (+ GUI, also in Python), so you can just import it and call it.

Comment: thanks,very helpful link !@JanezD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every component of Orange is run from Python, because Orange is written is Python. You can run individual components (say, for reading the data, data visualization and model inference) from Python as well. Documentation how to develop such components and run them is available in [Widget Development Documentation](http://orange-development.readthedocs.io). Besides unit tests for testing of GUI components, almost all widgets also include some test code which is executed just by runing the widgets directly from python (e.g., `python OWRuleViewer.py`).

You can invoke one or a number of widgets from your own code as well. For example, the following code would run a rule viewer widget:

```
import Orange
from Orange.widgets.visualize.owruleviewer import OWRuleViewer
from AnyQt.QtWidgets import QApplication
from Orange.classification import CN2Learner

data = Orange.data.Table("titanic")
learner = Orange.classification.CN2Learner()
model = learner(data)
model.instances = data

a = QApplication([])
ow = OWRuleViewer()
ow.set_classifier(model)

ow.show()
a.exec()
```

This script first reads the data (on titanic passengers), then infers the classification rules using CN2, and passes this model to a rule viewer (`OWRuleViewer`). Rule viewer is an Orange widget that displays the rules, and for the above example could look like shown below. Notice that the interactive part of the widget (selection of rules and with that selection of examples from which the rules were developed) is not explored in the above script.

[image: titanic rules]

Comment: Thanks. I am unable to run the SVMLearner and have created a new post. may you take a look at it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40838367/orange-3-svmlearner-cant-handle-mix-of-multiclass-and-continuous